# extracting html code from urls list

Tags: python, vb.net, visual-studio

**I want to get a html code value from many urls for the same domain and as example**
the html code is the name
and the domain is facebook
and the urls is just like

**https://www.facebook.com/mohamed.nazem2**

so if you opened that url you will see the name is Mohamed Nazem
at shown by the code :

**‏‎Mohamed Nazem‎‏ ‏(ناظِم)‏**

as so that facebook url

https://www.facebook.com/zuck

**Mark Zuckerberg**

so the value at the first url was >Mohamed Nazem<
and the second url it's Mark Zuckerberg

hopefully you got what i thinking in..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch the HTML page for each url you will need to use something like the `requests` library. To install it, use `pip install requests` and then in your code use it like so:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://facebook.com/zuck')
print(response.data)
```

Comment: Can't we use the vb.net for it instead of the python ?

Comment: Then why you tagged the question as `python`?

Comment: :"D i thought python is easy

Comment: and the script gives me an error :) i don't even know what does it mean

Comment: i think you didn't get me straight the code shows me all the code of the url and i just want the code that contains the name

Comment: @MohamedNazem you need to figure out where that is in the page data, since it would change on different sites. Probably look for the html id of the name object